# Why am I not friends with someone on my friend list

Tags: steam

I went to send a trade offer to someone on my friend's list on Steam and i had to go into my email to confirm the trade offer. In the email I see this

[image: You are not friend's with this user]

However, I am; as when I go into their profile and click "More" I have "Unfriend" at the end of the menu.

Is this just some bug with emails or has there been a step that either my friend or I have missed?

Comment: Has your friend added you back? you may be a follower, not a friend. it may have to be a mutual friendship to trade.

Comment: It doesn't look like a fake account as it is level 31 and has been a member for ~6 years but are you 100% sure it is your friend and not a fake profile?